# VBA Internet Explorer dropdown list trouble

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm trying to scrape some data using VBA via Excel. I'm pretty rusty with VBA but I'm confident in my google-fu, 5+ hours in and no luck yet. I have seen many ways to work with drop-down menus but none seem to work with this one. I have successfully navigated to https://www.kbb.com/used-cars/ but I cannot work with the "year" drop-down. Maybe I am not using the correct id/name? Any advice is appreciated, let me know if I left any important info out.

Code:

```
Sub WebForumEntry()
Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Top = 0
IE.Left = 0
IE.Width = 800
IE.Height = 600
IE.AddressBar = 0
IE.StatusBar = 0
IE.Toolbar = 0

IE.Navigate "http://www.kbb.com"
IE.Visible = True

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4


'Click on the "Used Car Values" link
Set AllHyperlinks = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("A")

    For Each hyper_link In AllHyperlinks

        If hyper_link.innertext = "Used Car Prices" Then
            hyper_link.Click
            Exit For

        End If
    Next


'Select model year"
Set e = IE.document.getElementbyid("yearDropdown")

Dim o
For Each o In e.Options
    If o.Value = "2012" Then
        o.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML there are no `Option` tags for you to select:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select id="yearDropdown" name="yearId" class="dropdown-one year-dropdown" data-default-option="Year" data-preselected-value=""></select>
</div>
```

The years are generated dynamically depending on whether you choose new/ used etc. So you can't select something that doesn't exist - perhaps you can directly set the value e.g.:

```
IE.document.getElementbyid("yearDropdown").value = "2012"
```

### Edit

Note there is an issue in your original code:

```
'Click on the "Used Car Values" link
Set AllHyperlinks = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("A")
For Each hyper_link In AllHyperlinks
    If hyper_link.innertext = "Used Car Prices" Then
        hyper_link.Click
        Exit For 
    End If
Next

'Select model year"
Set e = IE.document.getElementbyid("yearDropdown") '<-- error here if page not loaded per hyper_link.Click
```

When you call `hyper_link.Click` it will load another page (where the dropdowns are) and then per the `Exit For` the next command to run is `Set e = IE...` which will try and access an element that *doesn't exist yet* because the page is still loading per the `hyper_link.Click`. To work-around this you can just put in a pause like below:

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:04")
```

It's a bit of a hack - and there may be better ways to solve it - but it will allow you to set the dropdown per my first suggestion :

Full code (re-write of yours):

```
Option Explicit

Sub WebForumEntry()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim AllHyperLinks As Object
    Dim hyper_link As Object
    Dim e As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Top = 0
    IE.Left = 0
    IE.Width = 800
    IE.Height = 600
    IE.AddressBar = 0
    IE.StatusBar = 0
    IE.Toolbar = 0

    IE.Navigate "http://www.kbb.com"
    IE.Visible = True

    ' wait for page to load
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4

    'Click on the "Used Car Values" link
    Set AllHyperLinks = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("A")

    For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks
        If hyper_link.innertext = "Used Car Prices" Then
            hyper_link.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'wait 4 seconds - so page fully loads
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:04")
    'Select model year"
    Set e = IE.document.getElementbyid("yearDropdown")

    ' set a year
    e.Value = "2016"

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok I'm following what you're saying. I have tried your suggestion with everything that looked like an ID/name ("yearDropdown", "yearId", and "dropdown-one year-dropdown") but I get a runtime '424' object required error everytime. I can't seem to work with the "Used/New" dropdown menu either.  Any other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

> ...try and access an element that doesn't exist yet because the page is still loading...just put in a pause

Fantastic, thank you Robin!